# How execute pairwise.t.test into a list with `for` loop?

Tags: r

My list (`lt`):

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 2, 
    expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100)
  ), 
  y = sample(
    x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE
  )
)

lt <- split(
  x = df_1, 
  f = df_1[['y']]
)

vars <- names(df_1)[1:2]
```

I try:

```
for (i in vars) {
  for (i in i) {
    print(pairwise.t.test(x = lt[, i], g = lt[['y']], p.adj = 'bonferroni'))
  }
}
```

But, the error message is:

> Error in lista[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions

What's problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to `split`

```
pairwise.t.test(unlist(df_1[1:2]), g = rep(df_1$y, 2), p.adj = 'bonferroni')
#Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

#data:  unlist(df_1[1:2]) and rep(df_1$y, 2) 

#  1    2   
#2 1.00 -   
#3 0.91 1.00
```

Comment: The result is `<0 x 0 matrix>`?

Comment: @nerves  Sorry, I think I did the test on the wrong data.  You already have split the data into a `list`

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you look with `lapply` using a list (`lt`)?

Comment: @neves  The `g` can be applied there as there  is only a single group